# Android displaying html file with pictures and without internet connections

Tags: android, webserver

I would like to load a html file (with pictures and videos) on a Android tablet, however, there is no internet connection, thus I cannot use url for the pictures and stuff....

Is there any free web servers that allow me to do so (displaying the web content at local host)?

Or is there any way I can do it by writing a android app for it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webview's LoadURL method can take local content. using the `file` uri retrieving the content from your assets and render it that way. Assuming you follow the standard folder structure for a basic HTML website.

And why would you want to ask about "free web servers" if you don't even have a internet connection... All the content **has** to be loaded locally on the app or downloaded on the fly (assuming you don't download too much.. if its too much then you are better off packaging it in the app).

Comment: good to hear, don't forget to accept as an answer if it solved your issue :) @user1702061

Answer (score 0):

Without Internet your html page is static page.
You can store the html file in your local assets folder then:

```
url = "file:///android_asset/" + mName + ".html";    
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

and if you also want to show the images in your web page change the source path of images in source code of html page to local folder and pate all the images to that folder.

Comment: Thanks!! I got it now =] ~